# Permission denied. Failed to write file to printer at COM4

Tags: php, printing, port, pos

I am pretty new to this POS things and want to ask you for a little advice. My case is like so -
I am trying to connec to Eltrade POS device via USB. I am not familiar with the hardware but I think it is connected on COM4 port so I am searching it there like so:

```
try {
    // Enter the share name for your USB printer here
    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("COM4");
    /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    $printer -> text("Hello World!");
    $printer -> cut();
    /* Close printer */
    $printer -> close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

I get this information from Windows device manager from section Porst ( COM and LPT ) and this is how it looks like:[image: ports]

The error I get is :

```
Warning: file_put_contents(COM4): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\mike42\escpos-php\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector.php on line 384
Couldn't print to this printer: Failed to write file to printer at COM4
```

Where and how I should give permissions ? Is it about device permissions or some port permission ( if it has things like that ) ? I am working on Windows 10. I am using XAMPP. Thank you very much!
**EDIT**
Library that I use is [here](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/)

Comment: Maybe the COM4 is already in use? Do you have any other software running that may listen to COM4 or is connecting to it? I got this kind of results when I was playing with Arduino and Arduino IDE.

Comment: I don't think so. The port is showed only when I connect the device via USB. Otherwise I got only COM1 and COM3. Also it is shown as `unspecified` device in the `printers and devices` section in the control panel. I am not familiar with those ports. How can I check if it is in use from other device ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on Windows and COM ports, but it looks like you can try something like this: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P8CLSA0.